# Getting the supported IP version with NetworkInterface

Tags: java, network-programming

I want to code a program which shows information about your physical network cards. Not virtual or software-based network cards.

Now my question is, how can I find the supported IP version of my network card with `NetworkInterface`?

I need some detailed information about the network cards. How can I receive more informations about my network card with `NetworkInterface`?

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to code a program which shows information about your physical network cards. Not virtual or software-based network cards.".

That is most likely impossible in a virtual machine.  If the physical network devices were exposed to a virtual, it could do things that would interfere with other virtuals and the host computer.

> I need some detailed information about the network cards. How can I receive more informations about my network card with `NetworkInterface`?

I think that the best advice is to not try to do this in Java.  Certainly, using `NetworkInterface` to get more information than is available via the `NetworkInterface` API is ... nonsensical.